# how to replace url in achor tag if url does not starts with http or https?

Tags: javascript

I have this sample content on which i want to run the regex to pull the anchor tags whose href doesn't contain http|https in the address part and prepone that URL with base URL

I was trying with this regex, and it is not complete yet. I am able to pluck the anchor when they do not start with http or https.

```
   content.match(/<a\s[^>]*href\s*=\s*"(?!https?:\/\/)[^"]*"[^>]*>/g)
    .map(function (x, index) {

        x = x.replace(/href="(.*?)"/, function (m, $1) {
            if ($1.startsWith('/')) {
                return 'href="' + channel.link + $1 + '"';
            } else {
                return m;
            }
        });

          console.log(x);

    });
```

But the actual content is remaining the same. If I logged 'x' I got what I expected.what should I do so that the content has updated data?

Answer (score 0):

**Works only in Browser**
If your platform is browser, this will do the trick and does not require regexp.

```js
document.querySelector("#update-links-btn")
  .addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(a => {
      a.setAttribute("href", a.href);
    })
  });
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

a:after {
  content: attr(href);
}
```

```html
<button id="update-links-btn">click me</button>
<div>
  <a href="test.html"></a>
  <a href="/products/1"></a>
  <a href="products/2"></a>
  <a href="google.com"></a>
  <a href="//fb.com"></a>
  <a href="keep.google.com"></a>
  <a href="https://mail.google.com"></a>
  <a href="http://example.com"></a>
  <a href="https://cheerio.js.org"></a>
</div>
```